# capistrano deploy fails - fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I try to deploy my app to VPS via 'bundle exec cap production deploy', but I get an error

```
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@178.57.217.128
: cd /var/www/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD exit status: 128
cd /var/www/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD stdout: Nothing written
cd /var/www/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision
```

My remote git repository contains only one branch - master, and I have no idea what causes this error :(

remote git version is 1.9.1

local git is 1.9.5.msysgit.1

deploy.rb:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'stroysauna_pg'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:IvanSelivanov/stroysauna_pg.git'

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

`.git\config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 1187x555+90+96 239 251
[branch "lk"]
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:IvanSelivanov/stroysauna_pg.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

created an empty app from scratch - still does not deploy, same error
https://github.com/IvanSelivanov/vps

Comment: hope you have the latest version before deploying.Moreover check deploy.rb if you are missing some directives to define.

Comment: What does it say in your projects' .git/config file? There should be a section called remote. Might be something like [remote "origin"].

Comment: @JamesSmith, added contents of .git/config to question

Comment: @IvanSelivanov You seem to have two references to [branch "master"]. Don't think that's normal so might be worth deleting the one above [remote "origin"].

Comment: @JamesSmith Did it already. deleted 'lk' and 'master' "just in case". no effect. Now trying to create and deploy an empty rails project to see if it works

Comment: @IvanSelivanov Ah right. Also I don't think you need to do this but I always explicitly set my branch in deploy.rb: set :branch, 'master'

Comment: @JamesSmith same result.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution, but it works. Rebuilt server from scratch, but used rbenv instead of rvm. Now it deploys without errors.

Comment: Curious problem. Anyway, glad you've got it working now. Sorry couldn't have been of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Rename/delete the `repo` folder and redeploy using Capistrano.  Not sure what causes this issue, but this fixed it easily for me.